# Assigning resource IDs for raw resources

Tags: java, android-studio, resources

I have different .mp4 videos in my res/raw Directory in Android Studio. I want to assign them IDs so I can access them later on.

This is a snippet of my current code:

```
public Level(Context c){
  ArrayList<Trial> trials = new ArrayList<Trial>();
  String packagename = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
  String[] genders = {"male", "female"};
  String[] age = {"young", "old"};
  for (int i = 0; i < genders.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < age.length; j++) {
      int tempId = c.getResources().getIdentifier("android.resource://" + packagename + "raw/" +genders[i] + "_" + age[j], "raw", packagename);
      Trial t = new Trial();
      t.setResourceID(tempId);
      trials.add(t);
    }
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I also tried:

```
int tempId = c.getResources().getIdentifier("raw/" +genders[i] + "_" + age[j], "raw", packagename);
```

Both examples didn't work. The value of `tempId` is always zero.

Help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The second one is closer to correct. Remove the `"raw/"` from the beginning of it, though. Aside from that, we need to know the exact filenames.

Comment: I also tried that, forgot to mention. Didn't work either. The filenames: e.g. 'female_old.mp4'. All the names are a bit more complex than that, but I'm sure that the name is always spelled out correctly. I just don't know how to access the raw resources properly

Comment: Well, you've got the right idea, and that certainly should work, if everything's correct. Are you sure those resources got built successfully? I mean, does `R.raw.female_old` work if you try to use it in code? Also, are you certain that `packagename` is correct, and not empty, possibly?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Will try to check if resources were built correctly. Yes, I am certain that packagename is correct. Thanks for the advice!